# Express JS Node JS Static Web Development

Tags: javascript, node.js, static, routes

Located on [the api reference webpage](http://expressjs.com/api.html), it is shown that Express.JS using the function

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

should allow the static directory /public to be served.

here is my code.

```
    var app = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.listen('3000');
```

the response I get from the terminal is 
"express is not defined".

I copied this directly from working code,

why isn't this working?

Comment: short answer: var app = require('express')();

Answer (score 3):

From [the doc page](http://expressjs.com/api.html) you linked:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Compare that to what you have:

```
var app = require('express');
```

You need to define both `express` *and* `app`. Requiring express doesn't magically give you the variable. With *any* module, the `require` function loads the module into the variable you set it to.

Answer (score 2):

change your require to :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

the first will require the module, which later can be used for both the app itself and to call your static stuff. the second line will construct your app

Comment: after changing the required items here,